# Programmatically copy files from XP shared folder to W7 PC on the same LAN

Tags: windows, windows-xp, share, rights

Here is my goal :
I would like to be able to programmatically copy files from a XP PC shared  folder to a W7 PC in the same LAN without having to map a network drive (for instance I would like code running on W7 to be able to copy files hosted on a shared folder on XP PC in the same LAN).

What I have done so far :

- link the XP and W7 PC with ethernet
- Check that the two PCs are pinging each other (test passed)
- create a shared folder on the XP PC with full rights for all users
  (I checked full rights for the "Everybody" group of users). This folder's path is C:\test_share.
- create a file into C:\test_share folder which name is "test.txt" and wrote a few characters in it

My problem is : 
When I tip "\ethernet_adress_of_XP_PC\test_share\test.txt" on my W7 PC cmd console, which is supposed to open test.txt hosted on the XP PC, the following error occurs : 
"failed to open session : wrong username or password" (translated from french, might not be exactly the same in English). I did this to test the shared folder rights and if I can't display a .txt document, i can't copy it neither.

I would be very greatful if someone could help me with this problem. The difficulty here is that I don't want to map a network drive, I just want a shared folder on an XP PC to be accessible by a W7 PC on the same LAN whatever the user.

Thank you in advance for your answer, 
Best regards, 
François